# Docker port binding not working as expected

Tags: docker

Running a Jenkins image in my container which is bound to the host port 9090

```
sudo docker run -itd -p 9090:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name=myjenkins -t jenkins-custom /bin/bash
```

The output of running `$docker port myjenkins`

```
50000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:50000
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:9090
```

I can also see the binding from the host perspective `ps -Af | grep proxy`

```
root     15314 15194  0 17:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 50000 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 50000
root     15325 15194  0 17:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9090 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 8080
```

After starting my jenkins server i try connect to the container using the host ip and the forwarded port (9090).

I'm new to Docker so may have missed something however would appreciate suggestions

Update: including dockerfile

```
From local-artifiactory/jenkinsci/jenkins:2.9
ENV java_opts="-Xmx8192m"
```

Comment: Add your Dockerfile to your question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is not an answer to this specific question. It is a possible answer to "port mapping doesn't work"

I've been caught by this twice.

**The image name must come last when creating a container from the command line**

This syntax:

```
docker run --name MyContainer MyImage -p 8080:80
```

will create container `MyContainer` from `MyImage` without issue

**But the -p 8080:80 part will be silently ignored and your port mapping won't work**

This syntax will work - you'll see exactly the same outcome except that port mapping will actually work.

```
docker run --name MyContainer -p 8080:80 MyImage
```

Same for this:

```
docker run MyImage --name MyContainer
```

This will create a container from MyImage but it won't give it the explicit name, it'll assign a random name

I hope this saves someone some time.

Comment: OMG, I spent hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: OMG, THAAAANK YOU

Comment: This solved my issue! I was trying to create and run my container from Docker Desktop and couldn't figure out the settings. CLI seem like the best way to do it, this was pretty direct and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Port binding/publishing in docker is actually publishing container's port to docker-machine's, instead of to localhost's. For example, with
`docker run -p 9090:8080 jenkins`
you will be able to access the service by `curl <your-docker-machine>:9090`, NOT `curl localhost:9090` or `curl 127.0.0.1:9090`
To get your docker-machine's IP, do: `docker-machine ls` and check the `URL`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that no service is running at those ports.  The only process running is /bin/bash (as specified in the end of the line).  You must start Jenkins inside the container.

Comment: When I remove /bin/bash  from the docker run command I still have the same problem. Once the run command completes I use docker exec to start the Jenkins war.

Comment: Use the command to start the Jenkins as the `CMD` in Dockerfile:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the application in the container isn't bound to 127.0.0.1 but to 0.0.0.0. When the application is bound to 127.0.0.1 it will not be able to accept requests coming from outside the container. Binding to 0.0.0.0 means "bind to any/all IP addresses".

You can test whether you're bound correctly by trying to contact your container application directly. Look for the IP address in the output of `docker inspect <container_id>`, in a field named "IPAddress". Then use a tool like curl `curl -v http://<container_ip>:<port>/` or netcat `nc <container_ip> <port>` to check whether the application port is listening to requests from your host. If it isn't, then docker port publishing won't work.