# Docker container connection refused

Tags: docker

I'm using windows with WSL2 installed.
I built container with below script -- NodeJS server

```
# Docker script for nestjs server -- For testing
FROM node:18

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm ci

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

And build image with `docker build .`
And run with `docker run  -p 3000:3000 (NodeJS server is listening on port 3000)

And there are 'ping' http request inside server `http://<host>:<port>/ping` and should return 'pong' response.
I tried this request over different envs.

1. Windows (WSL2 is running and container is running)
   Send request via Postman

```
GET http://localhost:3000
```

response is

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

2. Inside WSL ubuntu

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

gets same response

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

3. Inside container

```
curl http://localhost:3000
```

reponse successfully retrieved

```
pong
```

Now I'm sure that server is running.

Container inspect list below,

```
{
    "Id": "c1191fd5b2deb5adcf89af8ccf5ea18812bee85bc9c3d90465e26a42ae2bfe88",
    "Created": "2023-10-12T09:50:48.266404824Z",
    "Path": "npm",
    "Args": [
        "run",
        "start:dev",
        "-p",
        "3000:3000",
        "--name",
        "test"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 19939,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2023-10-12T09:50:48.700406605Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:6912c4d03d52821984540a037ac30b1a3e7111bf9d560c0b99faafceb7559c58",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c1191fd5b2deb5adcf89af8ccf5ea18812bee85bc9c3d90465e26a42ae2bfe88/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c1191fd5b2deb5adcf89af8ccf5ea18812bee85bc9c3d90465e26a42ae2bfe88/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c1191fd5b2deb5adcf89af8ccf5ea18812bee85bc9c3d90465e26a42ae2bfe88/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c1191fd5b2deb5adcf89af8ccf5ea18812bee85bc9c3d90465e26a42ae2bfe88/c1191fd5b2deb5adcf89af8ccf5ea18812bee85bc9c3d90465e26a42ae2bfe88-json.log",
    "Name": "/admiring_albattani",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {},
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            30,
            120
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "host",
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/128326c1aa78b17594943f202a4c220a788ef6ba70bf96c4cc819cc68a133514-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c6b5zzb2ik0cfkf0ewps2bgwt/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/zr4cxqstgu02ra7glrh1qa08a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/s3imxggw3el9422u13dxe8v3a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/mh5zr4dyz1tvwxoz4b6p1binn/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0d234ff6425d4859ea83dee385320c4243bfdbfb91415fd89e663cd0bff0655a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6275f330dee99c6d3b688cde48fe814e1d30936789894bf2584c7944765301bf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/26fa7a8e809345b31f98c2e8261d60a15ce58a841e5b7b56556a050446acc827/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/79f57d81e2c97ab6aaf3d8f036a38356464cccc0fd62ac70f02bb15814dce841/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/28af674bb584053258e45168acf22851dc94b85714b51439fa23db9aec3be736/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/19bec54d77725cb724f285a52308b60955347376d383dcb86121292760edebd6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/451daadeb1dfc02492a68c327f3a4523d653fa67d3643a3f7ab46a123145f803/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c2e3da41d2357797896be0eadcb31e82fad1cb46113c7d9c09593a491c32d6e7/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/128326c1aa78b17594943f202a4c220a788ef6ba70bf96c4cc819cc68a133514/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/128326c1aa78b17594943f202a4c220a788ef6ba70bf96c4cc819cc68a133514/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/128326c1aa78b17594943f202a4c220a788ef6ba70bf96c4cc819cc68a133514/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "c1191fd5b2de",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "3000/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "NODE_VERSION=18.18.1",
            "YARN_VERSION=1.22.19"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "-p",
            "3000:3000",
            "--name",
            "test"
        ],
        "Image": "6912c4d03d52821984540a037ac30b1a3e7111bf9d560c0b99faafceb7559c58",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/app",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "npm",
            "run",
            "start:dev"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "db992a401db21abb9169c88b1a9b19aeb0baa3c396a6c1d997b56897e1c2adce",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "3000/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/db992a401db2",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "7a069d940d89b876d12d6c421ac5664819aa739ea906df22014566a742f6c848",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "302bd2351bcf5c2f5e57291b101ed1ee4cf80cdc98ff746dc12a73f65267aedf",
                "EndpointID": "7a069d940d89b876d12d6c421ac5664819aa739ea906df22014566a742f6c848",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Seems port is exposed.
And also tried `docker port <my_container_name> and it result nothing (I don't know why this does not show exposed port anyway)

`docker ps` result belows

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES
c1191fd5b2de   6912c4d03d52   "npm run start:dev -…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   3000/tcp   admiring_albattani
```

Can you help me about why my server is not accessible from outside of container?
All seems normal I guess.

I'm assuming reason for connect rejection is port is not in use but dont know how to resolve it.

Thanks

--- appended to post later ---

I also configure server to listen on 0.0.0.0
NestJS code are blow

```js
await app.listen(configService.get('server.port'), '0.0.0.0', () => {
        console.log(`=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=`);
        console.log(`=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Running NestJS Server =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=`);
        console.log(`=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=`);
        console.log(`   Environment: ${configService.get('server.env')}`);
        console.log(`Listening port: ${configService.get('server.port')}`);
        console.log(`=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=`);
    });
```

- I tried both localhost url 'localhost:3000' and '127.0.0.1:3000' on curl command and postman url.

Comment: What does the container logs say? Have you confirmed that your NodeJS application is up and running?

Comment: This possibly sounds like the symptom of an application that's configured to listen on `127.0.0.1`, but then is unreachable from outside it's own container.  You usually need to listen on `0.0.0.0` in Docker.  In your application code, is there a `app.listen()` call or similar?

Comment: @SebastianK Yes, the node server is running as it response with 'pong' inside the container shell.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm sorry for forgot that, server is listening on 0.0.0.0, I modified post with its code.

Comment: Did you [publish](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish) the port `3000` on host?

Comment: @msrumon Yes, `docker run <image> -p 3000:3000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOUND AN SOLUTION but not understandable.**

I found out that, I successfully connect to docker container after change port from 3000 to 8080. Just modify command from `docker run <image> -p 3000:3000` to `docker run <image> -p 8080:8080` with following server config changes(Just modified listening port to 8080)
I have no idea why this is problematic (Even there are no any process listening on port 3000)

What is changed in `docker inspect` is

```json
"PortBindings": {
  "3000/tcp": null
},
```

is changed into

```json
"PortBindings": {
  "8080/tcp": [
    {
      "HostIp": "",
      "HostPort": "8080"
    }
  ]
},
```

I don't know the reason.

Comment: Have you tried binding port 3000 on your host to port 8080 on the container? That would tell us whether the issue is with the port on your machine or inside the Docker container.

Comment: From the Docker inspect, it appear quite clear that the host mapping did not work for port 3000, as it is null.

Comment: @SebastianK I'll try and get back to you. And it seems it is not specific port problem, when using other port, it works greatly at first, but after few tries, same occurs on that port too. Every time it happens, I move to another port.

Comment: Sounds more like an OS problem then? Annoying problem for sure, hope you manage to find a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the container with 0.0.0.0.

$ docker run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 3000:3000 ...

Comment: This result in error message about `npm run script` command failure and container exited after running

Comment: What error would that be?  When did it error?  Binding to the host should not change your container.

Comment: Yes, it was very strange error, right after running container with your command. Error looks like when you mis-use wrong npm command (With showing 'refer to npm run-script --help')

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the port configuration flag BEFORE the Docker image, when running the container:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 <image>
```

Instead of

```
docker run <image> -p 3000:3000
```

Same issue that has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012346/docker-port-binding-not-working-as-expected).

Comment: I tried moving position of option '-p' before.